# Magento Secure Url 404 page not found in checkout/onepage

Tags: magento, http-status-code-404

I have magento site and I want to set secure url. I have set it from admin->web in secure url fields and set Use Secure URLs in Frontend to yes. But when I access checkout/onepage it give me 404 Not Found. The server can not find the requested page. Any-buddy have solution please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your SSL certificate is signed by CA, and that it hasn't expired yet. This may be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to open the your link with `index.php`, like [here](https://domain.com/index.php/customer/account/login/).

If it works, then rewrite problem.

If you are on `Centos`, you may find the `ssl.conf`, or check the `http.conf` which depend on your OS.

Find here:

```
<Directory "/www/web_root">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Make sure `AllowOverride All` is in there.

Then restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

Is it localhost, shared hosting or VDS/VPS? I think that you didn't setup on SSL for your domain on hosting panel. If you using localhost, you should generate certificate and turn on SSL in virtual host settings of your domain.

Comment: No its not localhost and my domain is SSL certified.

Answer (score 0):

This could also be a problem with the folder you're using. If you switch to SSL the server will look for SSL protected pages in the private_html folder. If your webshop resides in the public_html folder the SSL protected pages will generate a 404 error. Luckily this is solved relatively easy since you use a symbolic link from private_html to public_html. I have experience with Direct Admin and this is set by choosing the radio button under "domain setup" at "Use a symbolic link from private_html to public_html - allows for same data in http and https"